# handle useReducer if pass from props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, composition, use-reducer

I'm trying to make an overridable usage of a `useReducer` in a Component for specific use cases.

Following my overfly simplified working state of work :

```js
function defaultToggleReducer (state, action) {
  console.log('Default toggler used')
  return !state
}

function customTogglerReducer (state, action) {
  console.log('Custom toggler used')
  return !state
}

// Dummy wrap to log the initialization from `Togller` component to point the twice initializations
function toggleInitializer (state) {
  console.log('toggleInitializer')
  return state
}

function Toggler (props) {
  const [
    toggleState,
    toggleDispatch,
  ] = React.useReducer(defaultToggleReducer, false, toggleInitializer)
  
  // Here is the prt making the previous `useReducer` useless
  const state = props.toggleState !== undefined ? props.toggleState : toggleState
  const dispatch = props.toggleDispatch || toggleDispatch
  
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'add' })}>
      {Boolean(state).toString()}
    </button>
  )
}

function App () {
  const [customToggleState, customToggleDispatch] = React.useReducer(
    customTogglerReducer,
    false
  )

  return (
    <div>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Default</legend>
        <Toggler />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Customized</legend>
        <Toggler
          toggleState={customToggleState}
          toggleDispatch={customToggleDispatch} />
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => customToggleDispatch({ type: 'parentAction' })}>
          This is why I want dispatch
        </button>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

Here, there is something smell bad, I have no doubts about this is working but the fact where `useReducer` is called in `Toggler` even if not used let me suspicious. So, it's a dead reducer I think.

So my question is:

Did you have a way to achieve a `reduce` control from parent component properly (at least: better than this) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use components' composition to solve this problem. Break `Toggler` to two components - dumb `Toggler` that expects an outside reducer, and `DefaultToggler` that renders `Toggler`, and supplies the reducer.

If you need a standard toggler, use `DefaultToggler`, and if you need a custom version use the dumb `Toggler`, and supply a custom reducer.

```js
function defaultToggleReducer (state, action) {
  console.log('Default toggler used')
  return !state
}

function customTogglerReducer (state, action) {
  console.log('Custom toggler used')
  return !state
}

// Dummy wrap to log the initialization from `Togller` component to point the twice initializations
function toggleInitializer (state) {
  console.log('toggleInitializer')
  return state
}

function Toggler ({ toggleState: state, toggleDispatch: dispatch }) {  
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'add' })}>
      {Boolean(state).toString()}
    </button>
  )
}

function DefaultToggler () {
  const [
    toggleState,
    toggleDispatch,
  ] = React.useReducer(defaultToggleReducer, false, toggleInitializer)

  return (
    <Toggler 
      toggleState={toggleState} 
      toggleDispatch={toggleDispatch} 
      />
  );
};

function App () {
  const [customToggleState, customToggleDispatch] = React.useReducer(
    customTogglerReducer,
    false
  )

  return (
    <div>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Default</legend>
        <DefaultToggler />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Customized</legend>
        <Toggler
          toggleState={customToggleState}
          toggleDispatch={customToggleDispatch} />
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => customToggleDispatch({ type: 'parentAction' })}>
          This is why I want dispatch
        </button>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Oh yeah that's make sense! I was thinking about wrap in complex context then use Consumer blabla ... but it's simplier like this. Thanks !

Comment: You're welcome. If including some functionality as part of a component, complicates the usage, extract the functionality to another component, or to a custom hook, and use composition. Context is usually good as a sort of dependency injection, and to avoid drilldown, which are not the case here.

Comment: Yeah that's why I've not investigate too much this way. Note: composition was (and still) in keyword I was sure about something like that, it's exactly what I looking for :)

FYI: My final work include a `ToggleBuilder` with variant components (Of course it's not a Toggle Component but more an Accordion with design crazy features)

Thanks again !